# Caching wrapper/decorator for ExtAudioFileRead?

Tags: ios, caching, audio

I'm developing an iPhone app and I need to display a waveform. The waveform is created from the audio data contained in an AAC or MP3 file. I'm using the function `ExtAudioFileRead` for fetching data from the audio file and converting it to linear PCM.

My problem is that when scrolling the waveform, I need to repeatedly retrieve the same data from the file, once for every drawing iteration. This is too slow for smooth scrolling, esp because I need to retieve individual audio frames.

How to speed this up? I don't like the idea to have to manage `AudioBufferList`s in memory on my own.